# Link 1 server with 2 domains

Tags: docker

I have one physical server with Docker, my docker run 2 containers, two web app in two différents ports
I also have two domains.

Can I link my domains one by web app ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can put a reverse proxy that routes traffic based on the domain name in front of the 2 containers.

As an example, let's create 2 simple Dockerfiles to simulate your 2 apps. I'll use Nginx as it's a very simple way to create a web server. Don't get hung up on the fact that I use Nginx here. This should be your web app containers.

Dockerfile1:

```
FROM nginx
RUN echo 'hello from container 1' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

and Dockerfile2:

```
FROM nginx
RUN echo 'hello from container 2' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

Then we'll create a docker-compose file to run the 2 containers, along with a reverse proxy.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile1

  app2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile2

  reverseproxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And finally, the nginx.conf file that configures nginx to route traffic for 'domain1.com' to the 'app1' container and traffic for 'domain2.com' to 'app2'.

nginx.conf:

```
events { }

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app1/;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app2/;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can start up all 3 containers using

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and send a request to each container using

```
curl -H "Host: domain1.com" http://localhost:8080
curl -H "Host: domain2.com" http://localhost:8080
```

And the responses will come from the two different containers.

Comment: Thanks you !
I have add it to my docker-compose file and I have create new nginx.conf.
But domain is not accessible.. You can view my file here : https://pastebin.com/rknhDnRL
I dont understand why, with your configuration it work, but no with my dockerfile..

Comment: It might be because your containers listen on ports 8082 and 8083. The nginx containers in my example listen on port 80. Change the nginx.conf so it has `proxy_pass http://app1:8082/;` and `proxy_pass http://app2:8083/;` or change your app containers so they listen on port 80.